# Way to get multiple editext text?

Tags: android

Does exist a library that receives multiple edit text objects, get the text from them, and put them in new object? Instead to call getText for every field separately.

Comment: this is basic way to take data from EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Android databinding library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html). It help you to bind your data (as a Simple POJO) with views.

Comment: Thanks! That exactly what I looked for. Buy it works only to put data in screen. How do I receive input from user?

Comment: You use  [two way databinding](http://example.com) to achieve this. Hope it will help you

Comment: Your link isn't work. But I already got it. To use {@=} Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RecyclerView` to achieve your task, add `EditText` in your item layout file and in `editText` add `addTextChangedListener` listener which gives you 3 methods, in `afterTextChanged` save string to where you want, may be in an array.